# Work around firestore document size limit?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to store a large number of fields, like for a star rating system, but firestore only allows 20,000 fields per document. Is there a known way around this? Right now I am going to 'shard' the fields in multiple documents, and keep the size of each document in a documentSizeTracker document that I use to determine which document to shard to (and add to the counter with a transaction). Is this the correct approach? Any problems with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharding certainly could work. It's hard to say without knowing exactly what kind of data you'll need from your document, and when, but that's certainly a reasonable option. You could also consider having a parent "summary" doc that contains fields you might want to search on and then split all of your data into several documents inside a subcollection of that parent.

One important nuance here: the limit isn't 20,000 fields, but 20,000 *indexed* fields. So if you're storing a bunch of data inside your document, but you know that you're not going to be searching on all of them, another alternative is to mark some of your fields as unindexed (which you can now do in the Firebase console in the "Exemptions" section).

If you're dealing with thousands of fields, though, you probably won't want to exempt them all one at a time, so a better alternative might be to place your data as a map inside a container field (named something like "allOfMyData"), then just mark that one field as unindexed. That will automatically remove all indexes from any fields contained inside that map.

Comment: Thanks - good to know from another developer that my idea wasn't too crazy after all! I'm just sitting here in sorrow for the people that store each rating of a post in their app in a separate document as they sit there watching their wallet run dry from firestore reads! or maybe i'm overthinking...

Comment: We actually just released a video on this topic, which might help you out. Or it'll give you even more stuff to overthink. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s

Answer (score 2):

**Actually, I ran into similar problem with the read and write issues with Firebase. So, here is my conclusion:**

**# if something small needs to be written & read very often, then use Firebase Realtime Database**

- Firebase Realtime database allows fast writes, but limits concurrent users to 100,000
- Firebase Firestore allows a maximum of 1 write per second per document
- It's very expensive to read a document that only contains a rating for example in Firestore

**# if something (larger) needs to be read very often with writes usually more than 1 second in between then use Firestore**

- Firestore allows up to 1,000,000 concurrent users at current Beta release (they might make it more)
- It's cheaper to read a large document (less than 1 MiB limit) in Firestore than Firebase Realtime database

**# If your model doesn't fit into these two choices, then you should modify your model and split them into 2 models:**

- 1 very small model to store in Firebase Real Database (ratings for example)
- 1 larger model to store in Firestore

Note: You could use both Firebase Realtime database and Firebase Firestore in the same project. Don't forget to take into account the billing differences between both databases. and their different limits. I believe, it's best to combine them and use the good side of each instead of trying to force solutions into one of them.

Note 2: I really didn't like the shard-ing idea in Firestore suggested solution and work around

Comment: Ok, but what is the alternative to sharding? You have just eliminated the possibility of using realtime db for large amounts of data as it is more expensive than firestore.

Comment: Real time database is great for writing and reading small pieces of data such as the ratings you mentioned. It doesn't matter if the realtime database gets bigger overtime. Is there a reason you want to read and write the whole 20,000+ ratings at once? In realtime database you can even increment these ratings easily while in firestore documents can only be written once per second, so, it's not ideal for ratings and similar frequent and small data handling. I suggested the use of both databases!

Comment: but when I need to get all the ratings to calculate the number of them or size then it would be very expensive if every user got all that data from database.

Comment: With realtime database, you can use cloud functions to increment counters. Unfortunately, as far as I know, the increment counter doesn't work with Firestore as good as it does with Realtime database; probably, due to the limit of 1 write per document per second (thus shard-ing is suggested) which is not ideal for me. here's an example of how to do what you probably need https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPKA88_FmkA

Comment: Please, do take into account all costs of the different solutions and the user experience when uploading and downloading and how problematic if you miss count in each case (is it ok if you miss?).

Comment: One of my solutions is to run a script every 15 minutes to count all numbers added since last run, then record the value somewhere different. Ask yourself how important each number you need. In my case I'm using it for a store where I calculate number of orders and total sales. In this specific case, I'm keeping multiple counts and records. Some for live representation which is not that sensitive, and some for financial reasons, that I try to be very careful with.

Comment: @aldobaie I need to store 1000 users per client (500 clients in total) and each user has 10 attributes, but only 3 will be changed in the app such as image, status and time. Which would you recommend: Firebase Realtime Database or Firebase Firestore?

Comment: @AlitonOliveira, each has advantages and disadvantages, but in general use Firestore; Unless you have a reason to use Firebase Realtime Database such as cost of reading and writing! But it's hard for me to choose which is best for you. Remember Firebase Realtime Database is only available in U.S. server locations, and not available in other locations.